# Непростая cводная таблица в excel

Tags: excel

Есть две таблицы в excel.

Первая это список рабочих с полями **ИД** - уникальный для каждого рабочего, **Имя**, **Часы** - проработанные за день.

И есть вторая таблица с данными о выполненных работах с полями **ИД** - рабочего, **Вариант** - имя изделия, **Количество** - собранных изделий.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть задание - создать сводную таблицу которая считала бы для каждого рабочего его производительность за проработанные им часы.

Получается что столбцы из первой таблицы должны входить в итоговую таблицу как есть (то есть в ряд) а сводится должны только столбцы из второй таблицы.

А также добавить пару *Calculated field* которые могли бы использовать значения промежуточных итогов по вариантам и значения из поля **Часы**.

Но споткнулся я уже на первом камне. Не получается разложить в ряд колонки из первой таблицы.

Гладко было на бумаге но забыли про то что Excel не позволяет такое сделать.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите пожалуйста возможно ли доделать это задание используя сводные таблицы Excel или возможны другие варианты реализации.

Comment: `=СУММЕСЛИ(E:E;A2;G:G)` - сумма количества для одного `ID`. Далее '=часы/сумма'

Answer (score 0):

Для того чтобы посчитать производительность нужно знать ее формулу W=Q/T где Q - кол-во произведенной продукции а, T - время. Получается нужно количество разделить на время и получим производительность.